# "Student" is not defined, when definition is just above it

Tags: python, class

```
class Student:
    def __init__(Sname,Stnumber,Cnumber,IDnumber):
        self.Sname=''
        self.Stnumber=0
        self.Cnumber=0
        self.IDnumber=0

    sn=input("Enter Studentname:")
    stn=input("Enter Student number:")
    cn=input("Enter Contact number:")
    ID=input("Enter ID number:")

    StudentObj= Student(sn,stn,cn,ID)
```

Error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f3e61d3c7d24> in <module>()
----> 1 class Student:
      2     def __init__(Sname,Stnumber,Cnumber,IDnumber):
      3         self.Sname=''
      4         self.Stnumber=0
      5         self.Cnumber=0

<ipython-input-1-f3e61d3c7d24> in Student()
     23     ID=input("Enter ID number:")
     24 
---> 25     StudentObj= Student(sn,stn,cn,ID)

NameError: name 'Student' is not defined
```

Comment: You can't create a Student object inside the definition of Student... It's not defined yet. Try using a classemethod if you need it :)

Comment: Please read our site guidelines -- [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to start. We ask that the title of a question be about the *specific technical problem* you're having, and that the code included be the shortest possible thing that lets someone else reproduce and test fixes to that specific problem.

Comment: ...I've done some editing towards that end, removing code that isn't needed to show the problem, and making the title more specific.

Comment: It looks like you'r problem is just indentation and missing var. Pull the inputs and Student  instantiation out of the class, and into an `if __name__ == '__main__':`

The missing var is the `self` in your `def __init__(?missing-self?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, Sname='', Stnumber=0, Cnumber=0, IDnumber=0):
        self.Sname=Sname
        self.Stnumber=Stnumber
        self.Cnumber=Cnumber
        self.IDnumber=IDnumber

    def populate(self,sn,stn,cn,ID):
        self.Sname=sn
        self.Stnumber=stn
        self.Cnumber=cn
        self.IDnumber=ID

    def display(self):
        print("Student name is:",self.Sname)
        print("Student number is:",self.Stnumber)
        print("Contact number is:",self.Cnumber)
        print("ID number is:",self.IDnumber)

sn=input("Enter Studentname:")
stn=input("Enter Student number:")
cn=input("Enter Contact number:")
ID=input("Enter ID number:")

StudentObj= Student(sn,stn,cn,ID)
StudentObj.display()
```

There are several mistakes you have made.

First, the tabs as soon as you start sn will make it so that it is inside the class still. In python you need to take care of tabs.

Also in your `__init__` you need to add self as the first parameter to be able to use it.

Third even after this your code will display only 0, '', '', '' because you are not assigning the variables inside your constructor, which I have done

Comment: FYI -- the earlier downvote was because the first version of this answer didn't describe what was being changed as English text. That's fixed, hence the downvote being removed.

Comment: Oh I messed up the formatting, apparently the triple quotes only work properly if you start the code from the next line

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem, just move your input and object declaration outside of the `class` definition:

```
class Student:
    def __init__: ...
    def populate: ...
    def display: ...

sn = input("Enter Student name:")
stn = input("Enter Student number:")
cn = input("Enter Contact number:")
ID = input("Enter ID number:")

StudentObj = Student(sn, stn, cn, ID)
StudentObj.display()
```

You are also missing the parameter `self` in the declaration of the `__init__` method.

Comment: Also his init function won't work as he hasn't given self as a arg